# Should the recommendation tag be burninated?

Tags: discussion, tags

The [recommendation](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/recommendation) tag seems to be use for a variety of questions most of which could do without it. Should the tag be burninated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, when people use this tag, they almost always mean "recommender engine" here. Such questions should probably be tagged with [recommender](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/recommender) or [recommender-engine](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/recommender-engine) instead. All the more so since [recommendation](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/recommendation) is often used on SO to mean "asking for recommended resources", which is not the same thing nor a great type of question anyway.

Comment: I think the trend on SO toward more explicit tags has been beneficial, and I would strongly favor `recommender-engine` over `recommender` - either will show up as a suggested tag when someone starts typing r-e-c-o-m... so I don't see any benefit to the shorter one.

Comment: I was going to ask this question. How about "recommender-system" like on stats SE? http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/recommender-system