# Tags 'recommendation" and "recommender-system"

Tags: discussion, tags, retagging

I see there are tags "recommendation" and "recommender-system".

My question for discussion is:

*Is this on purpose? If not, should we merge them into one, let's say "recommender-system"?*

There are 92 questions tagged with "recommendation".

There are 59 questions tagged with "recommender-system".

There are 12 questions tagged with both.

I didn't read all questions, but at first glance it looks to me that there is almost no difference in thematics of questions tagged with these two tags.

I am aware of almost the same question from 2014: [Should the recommendation tag be burninated?](https://datascience.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105/should-the-recommendation-tag-be-burninated).

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of `recommendation`; it can be construed as an invitation for recommendations, which is a useless tag.

Answer (score 0):

I agree. I did the same thing - untagged questions that weren't about recommender systems, which was only about 10%, and then merged them.